# Dejar imagen por default ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagen

Buen día. Verán, estoy haciendo un proyecto que incluye un perfil, y ese perfil tiene la opción de agregar una imagen.
La cuestión aquí es que guarda la ruta de la imagen en BD y la imagen en carpeta. Pero al crear un nuevo usuario, el control Image está nulo.
¿Cómo puedo hacer para que, al crear un nuevo usuario, esté esa imagen por default?

Éste es el método para consultar imagen a BD:

```
    protected void ConsultarImagen()
    {
        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(cadena);
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
        string id = Session["IdUsuario"].ToString();
        lblId.Text = id;
        com.CommandText = "Select ruta_imagen from tb_c_usuarios where id=" + id;
        com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        com.Connection = conexion;
        conexion.Open();
        var dataReader = com.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Load(dataReader);

        if(dataTable!= null && dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string PathImagen = dataTable.Rows[0]["ruta_imagen"].ToString();
            string URLPath = "http://" + Request.Url.Authority + "/" + PathImagen;

            imagenPerfil.ImageUrl = URLPath;
        }

        conexion.Close();
        imagenPerfil.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: que motor de BD estas usando ?
donde creas un nuevo usuario ?

Comment: Estoy utilizando SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea una imagen predeterminada en un folder publico, cuando creas una nueva fila en tb_c_usuarios haz que ruta_imagen sea la ruta a ese folder predeterminado,

eso lo puedes lograr con un trigger, aunque yo lo haria directamente en el script que crea el nuevo usuario

**El Metodo facil seria modificar el codigo directamente y añadir un else**

```
protected void ConsultarImagen()
{
    SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(cadena);
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    string id = Session["IdUsuario"].ToString();
    lblId.Text = id;
    com.CommandText = "Select ruta_imagen from tb_c_usuarios where id=" + id;
    com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    com.Connection = conexion;
    conexion.Open();
    var dataReader = com.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Load(dataReader);

    if(dataTable!= null && dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        string PathImagen = dataTable.Rows[0]["ruta_imagen"].ToString();
        string URLPath = "http://" + Request.Url.Authority + "/" + PathImagen;

        imagenPerfil.ImageUrl = URLPath;
    }
    else
    {
        string URLPath = "http://folders/folders/imagenpredeterminada.png"
        imagenPerfil.ImageUrl = URLPath;
    {

    conexion.Close();
    imagenPerfil.DataBind();
}
```

Yo prefiero la opcion de tener la hubicacion de la imagen predeterminada desde el inicio en la base de datos para asi evitar codificaciones raras como la de arriba.

Comment: ¿Entonces necesito crear una nueva columna en mi tabla? ¿No se podría en la misma y sólo redireccionar a esa ruta? ¿de la imagen predeterminada?

Comment: lo siento, corregi la respuesta, no necesitas crear una nueva columna, simplemente en tu insert de tu nuevo usuario debes de insertar la ruta de la imagen predeterminada EN ruta_imagen. como es el insert de tb_c_usuarios ?

Comment: Oh claro, claro, ya entiendo. Lo voy a intentar. Gracias.

Comment: Gracias, funcionó a la perfección, ¡saludos!